# Accessing multiple selected items in a ListPicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I came across the new Toolkit for Windows Phone that has the ListPicker control. Now after my searching I wanted to ask you people if I could actually select multiple items in a Listpicker and then use them?

I've completed the adding and selecting multiple items part by using `SelectionMode="Multiple"`

The XAML Code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="TopStoriesListPicker" Margin="0" Header="Top Stories" Width="422" SelectionMode="Multiple" FullModeHeader="Top Stories" TabNavigation="Local" Style="{StaticResource ListPickerStyle1}">
                        <sys:String>BBC</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>CNN</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>FOX</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>SKY</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Now how can I access these items after they have been multi checked?
For one item I could have done:

```
if (TopStoriesListPicker.SelectedItem == CNN)
    do something
```

But now I have multiple items, plus the fact that these are no more proper items but have been defined by `sys:String`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting all selected items use the `SelectedItems` property:

```
foreach (var item in listPicker1.SelectedItems)
    Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you Heinrich. But what If there are multiple items selected at one instance, and i want another page to show both their contents. For example: If i select **CNN** and **BBC** both at the same time in the listpicker and then display both **their content on a separate page** how am I going to do that?
Isn't there a way that I could acutally identify which item(s) has been selected by the sys: syntax or something else?

Comment: When you select **CNN** and **BBC** then `listPicker1.SelectedItems` will contain two strings: **CNN** and **BBC**. What do you mean by "display both their content"? What are you trying to do? Where's the problem exactly?