# Issue with ListPicker "SelectionMode = Multiple"

Tags: c#, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-7.1

I have defined the items of ListPicker using "Sys:String", "ViewModel" & ListPickerItem" but in all three scenarios i wasn't able to use multiple items selected in the ListPicker.

The XAML Code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPicker1" Margin="0" Header="listpicker1" Width="422" SelectionMode="Multiple" FullModeHeader="Top Stories" SelectionChanged="ListPicker1_SelectionChanged">
                            <sys:String>abc</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>def</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>ghi</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>jkl</sys:String>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

C# Code

```
private void ListPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListPicker item in ListPicker1.Items)
            {
                if (item.ToString() == "abc")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

I want the selected items of the listpicker as strings.

I m also facing another issue the listpicker selectiochanged event is occuring when page loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing multiple selected items in a ListPicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345454/accessing-multiple-selected-items-in-a-listpicker)

Comment: i think we are facing the same problem, but my issue is a bit different. i saw the solution you gave on that question but that is only applicable when im using listbox. but here im using listpicker and that doesnt work. Secondly my listpicker_SelectionChanged event runs as if it is in the page_loaded event. anY solutions to that??

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `SelectedItems` property to get the selected items in the list:

```
    private void ListPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListPicker item in ListPicker1.SelectedItems)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Also, have a look at the [SelectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.aspx) class, it contains the items that have been selected or deselected in the current selection event.